# Open a workbook from VBA and disable Workbook_Open() code?

Tags: vba, excel

I am opening spreadsheets using VBA and a couple of the workbooks contain code which starts executing when Workbook_Open() is called.

How can I open the workbooks using VBA but stop the code automatically executing? I am only opening the workbooks to look at formulae in the sheet- I do not want any code execution.

Comment: You can always set your macro security to block all macros. This is probably not ideal, but should do what you are asking.

Answer (score 31):

Would you like to try **disabling** the Events before you open the workbook in VBA and then **re-enabling** them for the rest of the module?  Try using something like this:

```
Application.EnableEvents = False   'disable Events
workbooks.Open "WORKBOOKPATH"      'open workbook in question
Application.EnableEvents = True    'enable Events
```

Comment: If this doesn't work, the other way to work this around would be to declare a global boolean in a module and set it to true or false when you want or not the Workbook_Open() code to be run. You would have to add an If() statement to check the boolean's value in your Workbook_Open() sub.

Comment: Or look into using `Application.AutomationSecurity`

Comment: I think the macros are still enabled and could be triggered after EnableEvents is re-enabled.

Answer (score 24):

I don't know why this was not clearly mentioned in the other answers but I found `Application.AutomationSecurity` to do exactly what was required. Basically

```
Application.AutomationSecurity = msoAutomationSecurityByUI
'This is the default behavior where each time it would ask me whether I want to enable or disable macros

Application.AutomationSecurity = msoAutomationSecurityForceDisable
'This would disable all macros in newly opened files

Application.AutomationSecurity = msoAutomationSecurityLow
'This would enable all macros in newly opened files
```

Even after the code is run the settings will not revert back to the default behavior so you need to change it again. Thus for this question

```
previousSecurity = Application.AutomationSecurity
Application.AutomationSecurity = msoAutomationSecurityForceDisable
' Your code
Application.AutomationSecurity = previousSecurity
```

Answer (score 8):

Here another way to open with out the vba

> **`Start Excel Application > Go to File > Recent >`**

[image]

*Hold Shift key and double click to open -*

Doing this will prevent the **`Workbook_Open`** event from firing and the **`Auto_Open`** macro from running.

Or hold shift key and double click to open the Workbook.

---

> *For **`VBA`** Work with **[Application.EnableEvents property (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Application.EnableEvents)***

Comment: He asked about opening from VBA code.  Much harder question.

Answer (score 2):

A combination of **Application.EnableEvents** and a Workbook specific Application.EnableEvents works great.  Any time the workbook is re-referenced (such as copying cells) it will retrigger the activate events.  The workbook has to exit first, and cant be accessed after closing so try this:

```
Dim wb as Workbook
Application.EnableEvents = False
Set wb = workbooks.Open "YOURWORKBOOKPATH"
Application.EnableEvents = True
wb.Application.EnableEvents = False

**Code**

wb.Application.EnableEvents = True
wb.Close
```

Comment: There is no such thing as "Workbook specific Application.EnableEvents".
wb.Application = Application

Answer (score 1):

```vb
Dim xlapp as New Excel.Application
Dim wb as Workbook

xlapp.EnableEvents = False
Set wb = xlapp.Workbooks.Open("My workbook name")
'Process the workbook
wb.Close savechanges := false
xlapp.Quit
set wb = nothing
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Answer (score 0):

Open an empty excel macro file and put a macro with
Application.EnableEvents = False, And then open the file. After that do Application.EnableEvents = True.