# How to goto excel vba code when opening the macro opens Userform instead of Thisworkbook?

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I have written excel VBA code containing Userform and added code to show userform and hide Thisworkbook when the macro is opened. It shows userform during Start up. How to see the vba code, when userform is opened? Clicking Alt+F11 on Userform is not taking to VBA editor.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Open a workbook from VBA and disable Workbook\_Open() code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16301530/open-a-workbook-from-vba-and-disable-workbook-open-code)

Answer (score 0):

Press the `Shift` key and hold it down while you open the file.  This will prevent the macro from firing (I'm assuming you have `Workbook_open` setting both `Application.Visible = False` and your userform's `.Show` method?)

Comment: Yes. Am using Application.Visible = False and userform.Show. Tried holding holding Shift key and opening the file. Still, its triggering Userform while start up.

I tried the below and am able to view my vba code.
Open Blank excel first, then press Alt+F11. This opens empty VBA Editor. Now open the Macro, It opens Userform and its vba code in above empty VBA editior.

Thanks for your time.