# Open workbook with arguments

Tags: vba, excel

**Question :** Is there a way to open a workbook and pass an argument/parameter through this action ?

**The idea is** to differentiate the case where a user directly open Workbook B (which will trigger its Auto[_](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O70rA.png)Open code) and the case where Workbook B is opened from the code of an other Workbook[.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wdeBV.png)

Comment: How about this: you create an empty file (in the same directory) just before opening the Excel file. Then you tell `Workbook_Open` to check if this file exists (maybe even with a "password in the file"). If there is such a file then don't do anything but delete that file. Otherwise, do the normal `Workbook_Open` routine.

Comment: Yeah this could definitely be a solution if there is no easier way to do that

Comment: If you open a workbook in code, `Auto_Open` will not run unless you explicitly call it. If you meant `Workbook_Open` just disable events.

Comment: Yes I know, but I want it to run in both cases, differently though.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Open a workbook from VBA and disable Workbook\_Open() code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16301530/open-a-workbook-from-vba-and-disable-workbook-open-code)

Comment: If it's `Auto_Open` the calling code has to run it explicitly, so you could set a property of the workbook, or have `Auto_Open` simply call another macro with an optional parameter. That way the code can directly run the other routine and pass a parameter to it.

Comment: @Rory : This is exactly what I am trying to do, but I don't know how to pass a parameter from a workbook to an other one. When the workbook B is opened through workbook A, the parameter passed to the routine should be different than if workbook B is opened by a user

Comment: @Ralph : Yeah it's pretty similar I'll try those suggestions out thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The two options I suggested, in brief:

1. In the workbook you are opening, add this to the `ThisWorkbook` module:

`Public OpenedInCode as Boolean`

Your calling workbook needs to open the workbook, then use something like

```
With Workbooks("workbook name.xlsm")
   .OpenedInCode = True
   .RunAutoMacros xlAutoOpen
End With
```

Then the `Auto_Open` code needs to check this value. If it's `False`, the user opened it; if `True`, your other workbook opened it.

Option 2 is simply to create another routine with the code from your `Auto_Open` that takes an optional, say, Boolean parameter. Your `Auto_Open` code then just calls this routine. Your calling workbook would use `Run`

```
Dim wb as Workbook
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(path to file here)
Application.Run "'" & wb.Name & "'!routine_name", True
```

As with option 1, the called routine just checks to see if the argument is True or False and reacts accordingly.

Comment: First option doesn't work for me unfortunately. Did you try to implement it ? Second option does work !

Comment: I have used the first option before. I did forget to mention that the variable has to go into the ThisWorkbook module for the opened workbook - I will update my answer.

Comment: Tried again, doesn't work for me. Whether I set it to True or false in the `With` statement of the source Workbook, the Msgbox of the variable returns False

Comment: Are you using Thisworkbook.openedincode for the MsgBox?

Comment: Yes. Both `MsgBox ThisWorkbook.openedincode` and `MsgBox openedincode` return `false` whatever `openedincode` is set to in the calling Workbook

Comment: I'd need to see your full code to figure out why it doesn't work for you.

Comment: [http://i.stack.imgur.com/wdeBV.png] this is the code in the calling workbook and this is the code in the called workbook :  [https://i.stack.imgur.com/O70rA.png]. strFile is the full path (because the folder is differrent for the 2 worbooks)

Comment: Oh I see. You said you were using `Auto_Open` but that's a `Workbook_Open` event which will run before the variable is set.

Comment: Yessss it works now ! This way is exactly what I was looking for, Thanks!!