# VBA Excel | Submit information/modification to a worksheet before _Open Event executes

Tags: vba, excel

On its own workbook "A" starts with checking if there is a settings file saved locally, that stores the User's credentials for autologin.
If there is no such file, it will show a login form.

I would like to add now the functionality that if I open workbook"A" from workbook "B" it should try to fetch the logged in user of WorkBook"B" instead of starting with checking the local settings file first.

There is a variety of WB-s that could call "A", so i would not go for putting a code in A to check a cellvalue in B, instead I would like to have B modify something in A upon opening.

The problem is:
When i open "A" from "B", any modification is only implemented after every code executed from _Open macro, so it cannot recognize in time, that actually i would like to pass extra information to that process.
like this:

```
Sub Test 'In Wb"B"
    Dim Wb as workbook  
    Set Wb = Workbooks.Open(path)
    Wb.Sheets(1).Range("A1").Value = "NewValue"
End sub
'----
Private Sub workbook_open()  ' In Wb"A"
    MsgBox ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("A1").Value
End Sub
```

MsgBox will show "OldValue", because the external change will take place after the _Open event.
I have also tried to pass a parameter like `_Open(optional Modifier as variant)`, but as I suspected, Events cannot accept parameters like that, right?

**So how to provide extra info to Wb"A" from Wb"B" upon opening, before anything else happens?**

One possible, but not preferred method I can think of is via command line parameters, like discussed in here:
[Passing a parameter to an Excel file when opening it](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/Azure/en-US/bb9fa94f-a1d4-45cd-9279-b12e7a7e69c0/passing-a-parameter-to-an-excel-file-when-opening-it?forum=excel) 
Is there any other solution to achieve the requied results?

Answer (score 3):

you could use the last workbook opened before "A" as a "messenger"

for instance should "B" the last opened workbook, you would have the following `Test()` sub:

```
Sub Test() 'In Wb"B"
    Dim Wb As Workbook

    Sheets(1).Range("A1").Value = "NewValue" ' use a convenient sheet and cell in "B" workbook to store the value you want to "pass" to "to-be-opened-soon" workbook
    Set Wb = Workbooks.Open(path)
End Sub
```

and in "A" `ThisWorkbook` code pane you would then place:

```
Private Sub workbook_open()  ' In Wb"A"
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("A1").Value = Workbooks(Workbooks.Count - 1).Sheets(1).Range("A1").Value 'retrieve the value from the last opened workbook 
    MsgBox ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("A1").Value
End Sub
```

Comment: I came to similar thoughts in the meantime, also by browsing https://stackoverflow.com/q/42835915/5892997. <br> But instead of a random previous sheet, i will create a Specific save file besides the "local user" savefile that already exists, that will be called "LoggedInAs". This file will be automatically Deleted by Wb "B" upon closing, so it will only trigger action in "A" as long as "B" is open.

Comment: Sorry for not being able that help you

Comment: Actually you were very helpful, thank you. Note: Your solution might work quite nicely, but I afraid that the "last Wb" as reference would not be 100 accurate all the time, so this extra file will be there for certainity.

Comment: @ÁdámBukovinszki - I must voice my opposition to this plan: **I think it's a bad to have workbooks auto-deleting each other** (especially based on unpredictable conditions like existence of a resource system resources.)  There are dozens of things that could go wrong, and I foresee a tragic loss.  ***This idea should go back to the drawing board*** to find an alternate method of cleaning up dead files or whatever the goal is here.

Comment: @ÁdámBukovinszki ...  If you *must* get rid of files on the fly like that, I suggest instead of deleting, you *rename or move* the files (delete a week later). Also remember you don't get 2nd chance since VBA doesn't use the `Recycle Bin` by default -- although you can [make VBA recycle with this from Chip Pearson](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/recycle.aspx).

Comment: @ ashleedawg - Thanks for caring. No need to worry about a loss in this case, I have already implemented as following: The Caller workbook creates a file before calling the other, called LoggedInAs.xlsx It contains some infos about the user who is logged is, that is needed for the other WB also.(pw protected) | So When the New workbook is called, it looks for the existance of this file and if finds it, loads the data into itself and deletes the file. If there is no file like that, and also no local Default, the WB will ask the user to log in again manually.  Any danger you see in here?

Comment: (the reason i need to delete it immediately is because if I don't , WbA will always believe it was called fron WbB even if not. - so each call creates its own shortlived messenger file )