Open Excel with a passed parameter to a variable in a VBA module
I know just enough VBA to get myself in trouble.
I would like to open Excel from a command line or BAT file with a parameter such that the parameter is assigned to a VBA variable.
How?
The scenario:  My phone system can run a command line prompt when the phone rings.  With variables like the phone number.  So... the phone rings with a call from "13175551212".  The command would start Excel with the phone number.  Then... VBA would use the phone number in code (e.g. look the number up, load a form, whatever)
I'm good with the VBA part.  I'm not good at getting the parameter passed when Excel is started.
Can anyone point me to an example?
Looked at other examples.  I can't get it to work.

Do you mean a workbook_open event in vba?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42835915/open-workbook-with-arguments

This question is similar to: Open workbook with arguments. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

No.  I want to open Excel and pass a telephone number:  e.g. "Excel.exe /p=317-555-1212", where the telephone number shows up in a cell.

There is no way to pass the command-line arguments to a workbook, but some workarounds are available:

Use a text file. An external app writes data to the text file which then will be read by VBA code.
Set an environment variable, then read it in VBA:

In the bat file:
SET myexwbookargs=HJ;DHJ;KSD
excel mybook.xlsm

In the VBA code:
Dim BookArgs As String
BookArgs = Environ("myexwbookargs") ' HJ;DHJ;KSD


Use the Windows Registry:

' Variant to hold 2-dimensional array returned by GetSetting.
Dim MySettings As Variant
' Place some settings in the registry to identify the location.
SaveSetting "MyApp","Startup", "Top", 75
SaveSetting "MyApp","Startup", "Left", 50
Debug.Print GetSetting(appname := "MyApp", section := "Startup", _
                       key := "Left", default := "25")
DeleteSetting "MyApp", "Startup"


I had not thought of a text file as an intermediary store-and-forward bucket.  I'll explore that option - I don't want to mess with the Registry.
