# Disabling macros from other Excel sheets

Tags: vba, excel

I'm working on a few VBA macros in Excel for a project. Is there a way to ensure that VBA macros don't launch from other Excel workbooks when you are opening them through a macro?

For example, let's say I have a macro inside one workbook to open some other Excel file:

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Select 
PathName = Range("D3").Value 
Filename = Range("D4").Value 
TabName = Range("D5").Value 
ControlFile = ActiveWorkbook.Name 
Workbooks.Open Filename:=PathName &; Filename
```

What I've usually done is include a `Application.EnableEvents = False` to the subroutine to ensure that I'm not triggering code upon opening the other workbooks. This is also the methodology suggested by this prior [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16301530/open-a-workbook-from-vba-and-disable-workbook-open-code).

But two questions come to mind:

1. Is this "secure"? Are there other ways that users could write their own macros that execute on my active application even if I disable events?
2. Are there other workarounds besides fully disabling events? This seems somewhat limiting and almost "throwing the baby out with the bathwater".

Comment: use SQL to get data from the worksheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to open the file without the macros and it's read only.
When testing this, I can't even see the macro module in VBA editor for the opened file..

```
Application.AutomationSecurity = msoAutomationSecurityForceDisable
Workbooks.Open Filename:=strFilepath & strFilename, ReadOnly:=True
Application.AutomationSecurity = msoAutomationSecurityByUI
```