# Open Excel workbook without open workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have a complicated workbook which hangs up, if I attempt to open it using Workbooks.Open().
But this won't happen, when I directly open the file from my explorer by double clicking.

Is there some way I can open the file through VBA in same way as opening it by double clicking?

After opening the workbook should be accessible using the below code:

```
workbookName="C:\abc.xlsm"
for each wb in workbooks 
    if(wb.name=workbookName)
        Myworkbook=wb
    end if
next
```

Comment: If you try this code, will it work? `Workbooks.Open "C:\abc.xlsm"` Does it open the workbook?

Comment: Yes it opens the workbook and freezes it, and the white screen forever

Comment: Perhaps if you first use `Application.EnableEvents = False`? Your problem description suggests that the act of opening the workbook is triggering some event handlers.

Comment: If you are trying to open an XLSM workbook, maybe some macros on that workbook cause an enternal loop with your Active Workbook. As suggested by@JohnColeman, try opening it disabling macros. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16301530/open-a-workbook-from-vba-and-disable-workbook-open-code

Comment: Your code should do what you expect, it's not wrong. Does opening other workbooks work ? Where is your macro located ? (Module1 or in Worksheet ?)