# VBA Excel FORM, run debugger when form close button disabled

Tags: excel, vba

I have mistakenly disabled VBA Form Close  button and one command button which close this form as well as close the Excel.
Now I am unable to reverse it back, can't open program code.
Is there anyway to open program code while running FORM?

VBA Form in MS Excel 2019

Comment: Note: Form is open when we open the workbook automatically, MS Excel is close when we close form :(

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/33005112/7599798

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the Form opens in the Workbook_Open event.

If that is the case you can open your affected workbook with disabled events from another workbook and repair the affected one

```
Sub open()    
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Workbook.Open Filename:="your filename here.xlsm"
End Sub
```