# Only run my code when opening another file also with a VBA code

Tags: excel, vba

I have a Excel VBA (A) code that I runs daily. The normal process is to open an excel (B) saved in the same folder, make some formatting modifications to it and re-save it with a new name.  The problem is that now this new excel (B) also has some VBA codes that the owner is using for other purposes. When I open file B using my VBA code, the macro also tried to run the code already on file B. And I want my code to just ignore that. I have been opening file B and removing the code manually but I am sure there is a better way. I appreciate the help

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16301530/open-a-workbook-from-vba-and-disable-workbook-open-code maybe

Comment: Is that "some VBA code" the `Workbook_Open` event, as such a question makes sense? If so, you can initially disable events, open the workbook in discussion, programmatically delete the necessary event, do your update job and save it, as you need doing and reenable events..

Answer (score 1):

Please, try the next way:

```
Sub openWBEventsDisable_deleteCode()
   Dim wb As Workbook, wbFullName As String
   
    wbFullName = "workbook to be open full name" 'use here the workbook to be open full name
    
    Application.EnableEvents = False 'this does not allow the Open event to be triggered
      Set wb = Workbooks.Open(wbFullName)
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    
    Dim VBCompTarget As Object
    Set VBCompTarget = wb.VBProject.VBComponents("ThisWorkbook")
    
    With VBCompTarget.CodeModule
        .DeleteLines 1, .CountOfLines 'delete existing code, if any
    End With
    
    'do whatever you usually do...
End Sub
```

Comment: @Lety Didn't you find some time to test the above code? If tested, didn't it do what you need?